# Why Internet Sharing is shown like it had used cellular data AND WiFi in DataSense?

Tags: 8.0, internet-sharing, datasense

I was looking at DataSense data in my phone and suddenly saw this strange behavior:

[image]

As you can see the Internet Sharing used 268MB of cellular data and 279MB WiFi.

What it means? If I'm sharing internet how can WiFi be consumed?

Answer (score 2):

You are [tethering over WiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering) so the input is coming from data and the output is going over the WiFi network.

The numbers `268MB of cellular data and 279MB WiFi` will always stay pretty close together.

The question about why they differ at all is a lot more complex and is probably best answered by the developers of the app.

Comment: The more strange part is that cellular data is lower than WiFi. So how can I share more data in WiFi than I consumed with cellular data?

Comment: @VitorCanova *Might* be dropped packets, or something?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't think so. I think if it was the case the cellular data should be higher.